# Right channel audio only without changing bit depth via FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a stereo pcm audio file at 48 kHz and 24 bits. The left channel is empty. I want to result in a mono file from the right channel that is also 48 kHz and 24 bits. But each FFMPEG script I have tried results in the same sample rate but the default 16 bits.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [channelsplit](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelsplit) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -af "channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FR" -ac 1 -c:a pcm_s24le mono.wav
```

Or the [pan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -af "pan=mono|c0=c1" -c:a pcm_s24le mono.wav
```

Adapted from [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channels - Choose a specific channel](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#Chooseaspecificchannel).